# How do I combine strings and integers in a print statement?

Tags: java

I have just started learning Java in a college course. If/then statements haven't been covered yet but I figured I could try them on my own. I ended up with some syntax errors which I think I fixed, but now it seems like there are operand errors when I try adding a string with integers.

The problem given in my class was to ask the user for their name, hourly rate of pay, and how many hours they worked. I know the professor will soon ask us to ask the user if they get paid overtime. If they do, ask after how many hours overtime is paid. And then calculate the total payment, with any overtime pay being 1.5x of the regular hourly rate.

However I get an error in the last 3 print statements, which I assume is because I am trying to combine a string and an integer. How do I fix this?

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        double payRate;
        int hours;
        Boolean OTyn;
        int OTy;

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your hourly rate of pay?");
        payRate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How any hours have you worked?");
        hours = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your boss pays overtime. Answer with true or false.");
        OTyn = input.nextBoolean();
        if (OTyn == true) 
            System.out.println("After how many hours are you paid for overtime?");
            OTy = input.nextInt();
            if (hours > OTy)
                System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + ((40 * payRate) + (hours - OTy)(payRate * 1.5)));
            else
                System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + payRate * hours);
        else
            System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + payRate * hours);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing braces on your if/else blocks.  Strongly suggest you read through some basic java tutorials

Comment: What error do you get? Can you give the error stacktrace?

Comment: "However I get an error in the last 3 print statements". And what does the error message say?

Comment: (hours - OTy)(payRate*1.5) Did you try a multiplication here? If so, you missed a *. =>  (hours - OTy)*(payRate*1.5)

Comment: In addition to Taylor's comment. It looks like you know python, java works with braces `{}` instead of indentation.

Comment: Just a style thing, but prefer `if (OTyn)` to `if (OTyn == true)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `{}` on the ifs

```
if (OTyn == true) { //here
    System.out.println("After how many hours are you paid for overtime?");
    OTy = input.nextInt();
    if (hours > OTy){ // Here doesn need because it is just one line after the if
        System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + 
                 ((40*payRate) + (hours - OTy)(payRate*1.5))); 
     // (hours - OTy)(payRate*1.5) you are missing an operator between this expressions

    }else{
        System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + payRate*hours);
    }
} else { //here
    System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + payRate*hours);
} //and here
```

Plus for an IF statement that has just one line after it you doesn't need the `{}` as this:

```
if ( something )
   System.out.println("Something is true");
else
   System.out.println("Something is false");
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing one set of braces and an asterisk as follows.

```
if (OTyn == true) { // <-- This brace to open.
  System.out
      .println("After how many hours are you paid for overtime?");
  OTy = input.nextInt();
  if (hours > OTy)
    System.out.println("Your weekly pay is "
        + ((40 * payRate) + (hours - OTy)
            * (payRate * 1.5))); // <-- at the start of this line.
  else
    System.out.println("Your weekly pay is "
        + payRate * hours);
} else // <-- That brace to close.
  System.out.println("Your weekly pay is "
      + payRate * hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
double payRate;
int hours;
Boolean OTyn;
int OTy;

System.out.println("What is your name?");
name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your hourly rate of pay?");
payRate = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("How any hours have you worked?");
hours = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Your boss pays overtime. Answer with true or false.");
OTyn = input.nextBoolean();
if (OTyn == true){
    System.out.println("After how many hours are you paid for overtime?");
    OTy = input.nextInt();
    if (hours > OTy){
        System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + ((40*payRate) + (hours - OTy)*(payRate*1.5)));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + payRate*hours);
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + payRate*hours);
}
}    
}
```

Try this, not only were you missing braces, you also had a problem with this line

```
System.out.println("Your weekly pay is " + ((40*payRate) + (hours - OTy)(payRate*1.5)));
```

you need a * between `(hours - OTy)` and `(payRate*1.5)`to result in `(hours - OTy)*(payRate*1.5)` otherwise the string concatenation will not work